# Why isn't my foreach function running?

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a decimal -> hexadecimal color function for php, but like the eg. it prints out ff19a even though I want it to do ff190a. I'm assuming the if statement in my foreach function is not pulling through and honestly I don't know why. I've also tried

```
$value = "0$value";
```

which doesn't work either for the line in $hexadecimal[$value]

```
<?php
function decimalColors($red, $green, $blue){
    $hexadecimal = [dechex($red), dechex($green), dechex($blue)];
    foreach ($hexadecimal as $value) {
        if (strlen($value) == 1){
            $hexadecimal[$value] = "0".$value;
        }
        echo $value;
    }
}

echo decimalColors(255, 25, 10);
```

I would love to get a solution on this, and if possible the explanation to why it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going with splash58's answer, but I suspect you're trying to learn this stuff, not just get it done efficiently, so I'll add some details here.

You've got some misunderstanding on how functions work; they should take in some input and [return](http://php.net/return) some output. Yours is not returning any output, instead you are [echoing](http://php.net/echo) from the function (which is bad form.)

In addition, you are modifying one value and then echoing another, which is why you aren't seeing the changes reflected in your output.

Finally, you need to be looping with [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) using both [the key and the value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). The values you were modifying were `$hexadecimal["ff"]`, `$hexadecimal["19"]`, and `$hexadecimal["a"]` which of course didn't exist. Instead you want to modify `$hexadecimal[0]`, `$hexadecimal[1]`, and `$hexadecimal[2]`. The other option is using `foreach` [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), but that can probably wait for later!

Your code could look more like this:

```
<?php
function hexColors($red, $green, $blue){
    $hexadecimal = [dechex($red), dechex($green), dechex($blue)];
    foreach ($hexadecimal as $key=>$value) {
        if (strlen($value) == 1){
            $hexadecimal[$key] = "0".$value;
        }
    }
    return implode("", $hexadecimal);
}

echo hexColors(255, 25, 10);
```

Note, the [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) function simply jams together the elements of an array.

Comment: I think all of the answers here are valid, and you can learn much form all of them.  There are always many ways to do the same thing.  The important thing is to *learn*.

Comment: @miken32 wait I'm most confused about the $key=>$value because this isn't a multi dimensional array where there is a key and value. I'm simply storing the number into $hexadecimal so there isn't a key/value instance right?

Comment: @mathn00b When you build an array like that, there are implicit numeric keys set. Try sticking a `print_r($hexadecimal);` just before the function return and you'll see them as 0-2. I did make one mistake in my answer on that point, which I fixed.  A multidimensional array is an array of arrays.

Comment: @mathn00b One last note, you should name your functions based on what they do or return. I updated your code to name the function `hexColors()` because that's what it's returning.

Comment: @mathn00b if any of these answers were helpful, you should vote them up. If there's one that answered your question, you should mark it accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change this

```
function decimalColors($red, $green, $blue){
    $hexadecimal = [dechex($red), dechex($green), dechex($blue)];
    foreach ($hexadecimal as $value) {
        if (strlen($value) == 1){
            $hexadecimal[$value] = "0".$value;
        }
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
function decimalColors($red, $green, $blue){
    $hexadecimal = [dechex($red), dechex($green), dechex($blue)];
    foreach ($hexadecimal as &$value) {
        if (strlen($value) == 1){
            $value = "0".$value;
        }
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

That uses the *reference* form of the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) array, so that you can change the array values *by reference*, rather than being stuck with the *value* which will not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use old foggoten sprintf :)

```
function decimalColors($red, $green, $blue){
     return sprintf('%02x%02x%02x', $red, $green, $blue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just string pad your values with `0` and return that:

```
function decimalColors($red, $green, $blue)
    {
        return str_pad(dechex($red),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad(dechex($green),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad(dechex($blue),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

echo decimalColors(255, 10, 20);
```